# Simulink For Iterator iteration limit visibility

Tags: simulink

Would it be possible to show N (Iteration limit) value on Simulink For iterator block?

Marked with yellow: [For Iterator 0:N-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEV1I.png)

| On block we see: | For 0 : | N - 1 | Iterator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| and I would like to see: | For 0 : | 5 | Iterator |
| Similar to other programming syntax: for (int i=0;i<6;i++) | for (int i = 0; i < | 6 | ; i++) |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the value of any block property in the "Block Annotation" that will appear below (by default) each block.

Right click on the block, click "Block Properties". Navigate to the "Block Annotation" tab and in the text box enter something like

```
IterationLimit=  %<IterationLimit>
```

Close the dialog, applying any changes and the limit should appear below the block.

**Apply a Mask**

Another approach would be to apply a mask to the "For Iterator" block inside the iterator subsystem. Right click on the "For Iterator" and click "Mask", "Create Mask". Then inside the "Icon drawing commands" box enter the below script.

```
mode = get_param(gcb,'IndexMode');
if strcmp(mode,'One-based')
    start = 1;
else
    start = 0;
end

limit = str2num(get_param(gcb,'IterationLimit'));
disp(sprintf('For %i:%i', start, limit-1));

clear limit mode start
```

This will display "For 1:6" (for example) on the block rather than the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for an idea but this is not a solution which can be implemented in production code. We would have "For Zero-basen:6-1" next to the initial block description: For 0 : N-1 Iterator.

Comment: @rybka Perhaps you can provide more details in your question as well as a reason why this can't be done in production code. I was guessing at what I thought your question was because it is unclear.

Comment: Thanks you for interest in helping.
I am not sure what to add to the question. On block we see "For 0 : N - 1 
Iterator"
and I would like to see:
"For 0 : 5 
Iterator"
Like in other programming languages. So seems it is not possible in Matlab. :-(

Comment: @rybka I've provided another approach using masks. This is probably the only other way to do this.

Comment: The mask works super and looks natural. Thank you @scotty3785.